# Apache Cassandra / Presto select query

Tags: cassandra

We have 2 node cluster with RF2.  When we select data using Presto and passing all partition key in where condition. Sometime data is returned and sometimes it is not though the cqlsh does return data everytime.  a high level summary is like this -

Table X.Y with partition keys A, B and C

when run select query like "select * from X.Y where A=1 and B=2 and C=3"  It sometimes returns data on one node and sometimes it return on both nodes and sometimes only on 1 node. I am trying to run query using Presto-CLI.  One interesting fact is that if I reduce the partition key from 3 to 2 in where condition and reformat the query like this -
"select * from X.Y where A=1 and B=2"

or

"select * from X.Y where A=1 and C=3"

or

"select * from X.Y where B=2 and C=3"

It everytime retruns data on both nodes.

Please help here.

Comment: What does your primary key definition look like?